# WooCommerce Update Cart button disabled

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I've had a problem on the checkout of my site's page for a while whereby the Update Cart button is not working. If you go into the element where the quantity of the item is, and change the amount from (for example) 4 to 2 and press enter then it updates, but if you change the quantity and press Update Cart, nothing happens. This is the code for the button in my FTP, and I'm just not seeing the problem:

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
```

Inspecting the element in Google I notice it is down as being disabled, but I don't know where to enable it in the FTP:

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update cart" disabled="">Update cart</button>
```

EDIT: Moved comment into question

Though looking at the Coupon section of the Checkout, I'm wondering if the Update Cart button should look more like this:

```
<div class="coupon">   
  <label for="coupon_code">
    <?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
  </label> 
  <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> 
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> 
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?> 
    </div> 
  <?php } ?>
```

EDIT2: I found a temporary solution by going to:

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart.min.js

searching for:

> .prop("disabled",!0)},input_changed

and changing the !0 into a !1

This works for the first update to the cart, then it goes back to not working again, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the 
`<button name="update_cart">`
with an input instead

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
```

Had the same problem when updating woocommerce and noticed they changed some of their inputs into buttons instead, so just revert back to using inputs for problem areas.